# PIC16F1503 resets during relay switching of 1HP motor

Tags: microcontroller

I am totally new to this stuff. I have connected a 1 HP induction motor through a relay and it is switched by a PIC16F1503. I have connected a 10 uF 25V electrolytic capacitor with VCC and GND pin, is it OK to not connect any ceramic capacitor across because it's already connected to the 10uF capacitor?

Comment: Please be more specific, read the forum rules and draw a schematic

Comment: How are you driving the relay - direct from a pin on the PIC, or through a transistor? Also, do you have a back emf diode across the relay coil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...is this OK to not connect any ceramic capacitor across because it's already connected 10uf capacitor!?

No, you need some smaller ceramic capacitors. A couple of 100nF ceramic caps would be a good place to start. The electrolytic capacitors have a high ESR and are near-useless for decoupling high frequency transients (which the motor generates a lot of).

Sprinkle your circuit with low-ESR ceramic decoupling caps; place them *physically close* to active components, your MCU especially.

Answer (score 1):

Relays sometimes cannot be driven directly by the micro, as the power they require is too big compared to what the micro can output. If this is the case, you will need a dedicated circuit or IC to drive it.
It would be helpful if you could give more information about the relay you're using and the way you're driving it.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the Voltage is dropped down during short period because the starting current is high, I think it needs more capacitance or powerful PSU. In anotrer case it may to do that MCU will go to be reset by itself.